# Can Lambda Integration for API Gateway return a custom object?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using a standard (not proxy) Lambda integration for API Gateway.

My Lambda handler looks like this:

```
public class MyAPI implements RequestHandler<CustomRequest, CustomResponse> {

    public CustomResponse handleRequest(CustomRequest request, Context lambdaContext) {\
        ....
        ....
        //create an object of the custom response and return it
        return CustomResponse.builder()....build();
    }
}
```

Now the integration response is always empty. There is no error in the API Gateway logs.

For a proxy integration I know that the integration response should be of the type:

```
{
    statusCode: "...",            // a valid HTTP status code
    headers: { 
        custom-header: "..."      // any API-specific custom header
    },
    body: "...",                  // a JSON string.
    isBase64Encoded:  true|false  // for binary support
}
```

But can't we return a custom object for a regular integration and have it serialized by API Gateway?

Comment: What response mappings have you set in the API-Gateway?

Comment: I tried adding mappings for the integration response. However the response from the endpoint itself shows up as empty when i return the object. It seems like API Gateway isn't able to do the serialization even though the object i'm using is clearly serializable.